# Set VaadinServlet ProductonMode when declared as Bean

Tags: java, vaadin7, karaf, blueprint-osgi

We are using Vaadin7 in a larger OSGI (karaf 4) application and have the VaadinServlet declared using blueprint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint default-activation="eager" xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
<!-- Vaadin servlet serving static Vaadin resources -->
<service interface="javax.servlet.Servlet">
  <service-properties>
    <entry key="servlet-name" value="Vaadin Resources" />
    <entry key="alias" value="/VAADIN-ui" />
    <entry key="contextId" value="app-vaadin" />
  </service-properties>
  <bean class="com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet" />
</service>
```

By default Vaadin runs in debug mode and has a setting of ProductionMode which needs to set to true. This can done as a context-param but the application does not use a web.xml file. I've tried to set it as property of the bean but it is not recognised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend `VaadinServlet` and use [`VaadinServletConfiguration`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/annotations/VaadinServletConfiguration.html) annotation.

From docs:

> Annotation for configuring subclasses of VaadinServlet. For a
>   VaadinServlet class that has this annotation, the defined values are
>   read during initialization and will be available using
>   DeploymentConfiguration.getApplicationOrSystemProperty(String, String)
>   as well as from specific methods in DeploymentConfiguration. Init
>   params defined in web.xml or the @WebServlet annotation take
>   precedence over values defined in this annotation.

You can use it like this:

```
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false)
public class MyAppServlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to go about  that as none of the JAVA code declares a VaadinServlet, it is only referred to in the blueprint XML. In fact there are a couple of servlets declared in different bundles. The one above is just for handling resources, another starts up UIProvider class.

Comment: You are using default `VaadinServlet` implementation (`com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet`), that's why it's not in your Java code. You can create your own servlet class extending default one (it may be empty as in the example above) and then set it in your blueprint xml. Reading [offical docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-environment.html) may help you to understand it better.

Comment: Thanks, I did read a lot of docs but managed not to have found that page.